# Dígito de un número y su posición en Java

Tags: java, string

Tengo un String del cual quiero saber qué carácter ocupa cada posición, por ejemplo:

Tengo el String: `7348` y al ejecutar el código quiero que me devuelva:

```
El numero 7 ocupa el primer lugar, el 3 el segundo.
```

Código Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String Str2 = new String("7348" );
  System.out.print("String Length :" );
  System.out.println(Str2.length());
  System.out.println(Str2[0]);
}
```

Comment: ...y, ¿cual es el problema?

Comment: Utiliza el método Str2.charAt(0);
En C# creo que es de donde vienes permite eso, en java no, así que utiliza el método de tu variable como muestro y solo aparecerá el 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma.

```
char [] fromString = Str2.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < fromString.length ; i++) {
   System.out.println("El Valor" + fromString[i] +" Ocupa el : " + i +" Lugar");
}
```

Esto para no tener un segunda búsqueda con el método `indexOf` de la clase `String`.

Answer (score 2):

Con el método [**indexOf**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) de la clase `String` que tomará como parámetro el **Carácter o Cadena a Buscar**, está claro que al String lo tomará como una `array` de caracteres, y la primera posición será `0` , solo se tendría que sumar `1` para tener el valor deseado.

```
  String Str2 = new String("7348" );
  System.out.println("El Número 7 Ocupa el "  +(Str2.indexOf("7")+1) + " Lugar");
```

Para evitar tantas Impresiones y hacerlo de manera dinámica para que **funcione con cualquier cadena** , podemos hacerlo mediante un `bucle` , convirtiendo la cadena en Un Arreglo de Caracteres haciendo usa de la función [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray())

```
 char[] valores =Str2.toCharArray();
 for (int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("El Valor " + valores[i]+" Ocupa el : " +(i+1)+" Lugar");
 }
```

> Para este caso simple la mejor opción es la segunda planteada. Pero tener en cuenta que el método `indexOf` será la mejor opción para saber en que posición está un `String` dentro de Otro `String` y no solo un Caracter. 
>   Revisar también el método [**lastIndexOf**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) que nos ayudará cuando el valor buscado se repita , este método tomará la ultima aparición.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el método **[indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) para buscar el indice donde se encuentra el elemento** en el string, s**i deseas la posición simplemente aumenta en 1 el valor del indice**, por ejemplo:

```
String Str2 = new String("7348");
System.out.println("El número 7 Ocupa el "  + (Str2.indexOf("7") + 1) + " Lugar");
System.out.println("El número 3 Ocupa el "  + (Str2.indexOf("3") + 1) + " Lugar");
```

Salida:

```
El número 7 Ocupa el 1 Lugar
El número 3 Ocupa el 2 Lugar
```

---

Otra forma es realizar lo mismo, obteniendo el indice donde se encuentra el elemento + 1, pero obteniendo los valores por medio de un arreglo de Strings **esto para que funcione con cualquier cantidad de elementos a buscar en la cadena**:

```
String[] numeros = {"7", "3"};
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length ; i++) {
   System.out.println("El número " + numeros[i] +" Ocupa el " + (i+1) +" Lugar");
}
```

Teniendo como salida:

```
El número 7 Ocupa el 1 Lugar
El número 3 Ocupa el 2 Lugar
```